# label: before if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, return, label

Hi I have function in Java and I want to see what will getResult("92972317") return..
I have no idea what label: before if means..  here's the code:

```
public static int getResult(String paramString)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int k = 0;
    if (k >= paramString.length()) {
      return i * 3 + 5371;
    }
    int m = Integer.parseInt(paramString.substring(k, k + 1));
    if (j != 0)
    {
      i += m * 7;
      label47:
      if (j == 0) {
        break label70;
      }
    }
    label70:
    for (j = 0;; j = 1)
    {
      k += 1;
      break;
      i += m * 3;
      break label47;
    }
  }
```

What I want to know is what these "label47:" and "label70:" before if statements mean and what it does..
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Who put those labels there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like whoever annotated the code was just using the labels as some kind of goto statement. But there are no goto statements in java. When I try to compile this code it doesn't even work when I try using java8. Looks like trash code to me.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what (j=0;;j=1) means here?
for (j = 0;; j = 1)
    {
      k += 1;
      break;
      i += m * 3;
      break label47;
    }

Comment: Yes like I said; it looks like whoever wrote the code was trying to use the labels as a goto statement. However the code doesn't even compile so it seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

Best reference to start off with java labeled and unlabeled `break` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) at Oracle docs.